# How to load video HTML5 after DOM and play in loop?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, video, html5-video

I have problem with load video html5 after DOM and play in loop. Video load correctly after DOM but when video start play again is load again. I want to load video one time and replay.

```
<video id="video" muted="true" style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;">
            <source type="video/mp4" id="mp4">
            <source type="video/webm" id="webm">
</video>
```

my script

```
var video = $('#video')[0];
var mp4Vid = $('#mp4');
var webmVid = $('#webm');   
mp4Vid.attr('src', "video/video.mp4");
webmVid.attr('src', "video/video.webm");
video.load();
video.play();
var videoloop = video;
videoloop.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.play();    
}, false);
```

EDIT//
Problem solved
It is because I have Chrome set to "Disable Cache (while devtools is open)

Comment: wrap the code in a `  $(function() {});` to execute it after dom load

Comment: I have this code and video load correctly after DOM but when this video play again is download from server again and play. I want to download video once and play in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `preload="auto"`, should load the entire video when the page loads

```
<video preload="auto" id="video" muted="true" style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;">
            <source type="video/mp4" id="mp4">
            <source type="video/webm" id="webm">
</video>
```

Comment: this solution don't work, video isn't load after DOM

Comment: Are you sure? The preload attribute is not supported in IE only. Remove in your javascript the line: `video.load();`

Comment: Problem solved. It is because I have Chrome set to "Disable Cache (while devtools is open) Now video is play from cache